# find and copy files and directories

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create bash script that will copy files that was created or modificated in last 24 hours. I know that isnot a new question, but i cant find answers that can help me. So i have dir `test` (all files/dir of them is created in last 24 h).

```
test/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    dir/
             file.txt
```

How can i copy them in format like this:

```
backup/
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      dir/
               file.txt
```

Because if i use `find test -type f -ctime -1 -exec cp -r {} backup \;`

```
backup/
      file.txt
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
```

or `find test -exec -ctime -1 cp -r {} backup \;`:

```
backup/
    file.txt
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    test/
             file1.txt
             file2.txt
             dir/
                      file.txt
    dir/
             file.txt
```

Comment: For a partial answer see, e.g., this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112407/199224 for listing files younger than 24 hours using the `-mmin -$((60*24))` option of `find`

Comment: oh, i messed up, forgot to type `-ctime -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hackish and probably slow due to bash but, this should do the trick:

```
find test -type f -mtime -1 -exec bash -c '
    src=("$@")
    dst=("${@/#test/backup}")
    mkdir -p "${dst[@]%/*}"
    for i in "${!src[@]}"; do
        cp "${src[i]}" "${dst[i]}"
    done
' _ {} +
```

`_` at the end is a placeholder for `$0` (you know `$@` expands to `$1`, `$2`, ...).

For a dry-run insert `echo` before `mkdir` and `cp`.